# Map values from more dataframes to one by multiple values in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I need help with some a little tricky mapping for me.

It's not difficult to map on clean one value, but now I have multiple values in one cell to map on. There is no rule how many values can be, but the most often is between 1 and 4.

Dataframes looks like this:

```
df:
flag   id
 1   [A],[D]
 2   [B]
 3   [D],[E]
 3   [B],[C]

df1:
id   col1     col2     col3
A     on        1      true
B     on        2      true
C     off       4      true
D     off       4      false
E     on        2      true

df2:
id   col1     col2     col3
A     on        1      true
B     on        2      true
C     off       4      true
D     off       4      false
E     on        2      true

df3:
id   col1     col2     col3
A     on        4      true
B     off       6      true
C     off       4      false
D     on        3      false
E     on        2      true
```

I need to map all three columns (col1, col2, col3), so I append it to one column and that's how it needs to be.

```
df1['Description'] = df1['col1'] + ', ' + df1['col2'] + ', ' + df1['col3']
```

And same for df2 and df3. 
And depends on column "flag" from df from which dataframe I'm going to take that, 1 is from df1, 2 from d2 and 3 from df3. 
Now I have a trouble with a lot of hard coding, I started with splitting into multiple rows (each value in a list in df['id']) then mapping, a lot of groupby and merging and there is big chance to fail at some point.

So, If there is any step to just parse and map from another dataframe, without splitting column values into multiple columns or rows?

I have tried with something like this:

```
for a in df['flag'].values:
    if a == '1':
        df['Description'] = df['id'].map(df1.set_index('id')['Description'])
    elif a == '2':
        df['Description'] = df['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['Description'])
    elif a == '3':
        df['Description'] = df['id'].map(df3.set_index('id')['Description'])
    else:
        df['Description'] = 'No RAT data'
```

But I'm getting NaN values. 
Desired output:

```
flag   id        Description
 1   [A],[D]   (on, 1, true), (off, 4, false)
 2   [B]       (on, 2, true)
 3   [D],[E]   (on, 2, true), (on, 2, true)
 3   [B],[C]   (off, 6, true), (off, 4, false)
```

Any kind of help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a new dataframe, the write like

```
d = {'col1':[0,0,0,0,0],'col2':[0,0,0,0,0],'col3':[0,0,0,0,0]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
new_df['col1']=df1['col1']
new_df['col2']=df1['col2']
new_df['col3']=df1['col3']
```

check it

Comment: I don't get it, how this is related to my question?

Comment: I have figured why there is NaN and that worked now, but I'm sure there is a simpler way.